# Not able to pull changes from Source tree

Tags: ios, xcode, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

When I am trying to pull the changes of my iOS app from SourceTree to my local computer. It is cloned with Bitbucket. I am getting the following error, on trying to Pull the recent changes or checking out a new branch:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by
>
> merge:
>
> test.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
>
> Aborting

Comment: The error message tells you precisely what the problem is and what you should do next.

Answer (score 2):

You have local changes in your working directory. You need either commit those changes or discard or stash those local changes. Then pull latest from remote repo